# A system of ordinary differential equations is being recognized as a DAE

Tags: plotting, implicit

I want a function `auxiliarfunction` that depends on two variables: `ρh` and `ν`. I need to plot the implicit function defined as `auxiliarfunction==0`. However, this function is a bit messy and I haven't been able to plot it directly using `CountourPlot`. The good thing is that that function is defined as an intersection of various curves that are also defined implicitly so I am trying to use pseudo-arclength continuation using each of those conditions to simplify the problem. In particular, I have the following piece of code:

```
f1 = c*(S*A^2)/H - mu*A + ρa*Y;
f2 = c*S*A^2 - ν*H + ρh*Y;
f3 = c0 - γ*S - ϵ*Y*S;
f4 = d*A - e*Y + Y^2/(1 + f*Y^2);
eq = Solve[{f1 == 0, f2 == 0, f3 == 0, f4 == 0}, {A, H, S, Y}][[3]];
jacobianmat = D[{f1, f2, f3, f4}, {{A, H, S, Y}}];
diffmatrix = DiagonalMatrix[{D1, D2, D3, D4}];
det = Simplify[Det[jacobianmat - μ*diffmatrix]];
der = Simplify[D[det, μ]];
ksquared = Solve[der == 0, μ][[1]];
c = 0.002;
mu = 0.16;
ρa = 0.005;
c0 = 0.02;
γ = 0.02;
ϵ = 0.1;
d = 0.008;
e = 0.1;
f = 10.0;
D1 = 0.001;
D2 = 0.02;
D3 = 0.01;
D4 = 10^-7;
ksquared = ksquared /. eq;
auxiliarfunction = det /. ksquared /. eq;
initialν = ν /. Quiet@FindRoot[auxiliarfunction == 0 /. ρh -> 1.0011*10^-5, {ν, 0.04}];
initialμ = (ksquared /. ν -> initialν /. ρh -> 1.0011*10^-5)[[1]][[2]];
initialvar = eq /. ν -> initialν /. ρh -> 1.0011*10^-5;
detaux = det /. ν -> ν[t] /. ρh -> ρh[t] /. μ -> μ[t] /. A -> A[t] /. S -> S[t] /. 
    Y -> Y[t] /. H -> H[t];
deraux = der /. ν -> ν[t] /. ρh -> ρh[t] /. μ -> μ[t] /. A -> A[t] /. S -> S[t] /. 
    Y -> Y[t] /. H -> H[t];
f1aux = f1 /. ν -> ν[t] /. ρh -> ρh[t] /. μ -> μ[t] /. A -> A[t] /. S -> S[t] /. 
    Y -> Y[t] /. H -> H[t];
f2aux = f2 /. ν -> ν[t] /. ρh -> ρh[t] /. μ -> μ[t] /. A -> A[t] /. S -> S[t] /. 
    Y -> Y[t] /. H -> H[t];
f3aux = f3 /. ν -> ν[t] /. ρh -> ρh[t] /. μ -> μ[t] /. A -> A[t] /. S -> S[t] /. 
    Y -> Y[t] /. H -> H[t];
f4aux = f4 /. ν -> ν[t] /. ρh -> ρh[t] /. μ -> μ[t] /. A -> A[t] /. S -> S[t] /. 
    Y -> Y[t] /. H -> H[t];
detaux = D[detaux, t];
deraux = D[deraux, t];
f1aux = D[f1aux, t];
f2aux = D[f2aux, t];
f3aux = D[f3aux, t];
f4aux = D[f4aux, t];
sol = NDSolve[{detaux == 0, deraux == 0, f1aux == 0, f2aux == 0, f3aux == 0, f4aux == 0,
    ν'[t]^2 + ρh'[t]^2 + μ'[t]^2 + A'[t]^2 + H'[t]^2 + S'[t]^2 + Y'[t]^2 == 1,
    ρh[0] == 1.0011*10^-5, ν[0] == initialν, μ[0] == initialμ,
    A[0] == initialvar[[1]][[2]], H[0] == initialvar[[2]][[2]], 
    S[0] == initialvar[[3]][[2]], Y[0] == initialvar[[4]][[2]]},
    {ν[t], ρh[t], μ[t], A[t], H[t], S[t], Y[t]}, {t, -100, 100}, 
   Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"];
```

It is relevant to notice here that some of the initial conditions are complex. For that reason, I am deriving each of the functions of the system with respect to `t`. The problem is that still Mathematica recognizes the system as a DAE and I don't know why. After running the code shown above, I get the following warning:

[image: Warning]

The problem is that if I change the method following the instruction of the warning, I get a second warning:

[image: Second warning]

The question is: what should I do to overcome the problems with the warnings? Is there a way to use the suggested method but integrate the system with a Non-IDA method? I have tried this approach with other systems of equations and it works well, but I don't know what to do in this case.

Comment: Could you explain mathematically what do you try to solve?

Comment: I've got a system of four reaction-diffusion equations. `f1`, `f2`, `f3` and `f4` are only the kinetics. I want to plot a Turing bifurcation curve. I know that the third equilibrium of the system goes through this bifurcation when we take the parameter values provided. The conditions for this bifurcation are essentially two: 
1.-The determinant of the jacobian matrix of the system including diffusion is equal to zero and
2.-The derivative of the zero-eigenvalue of the system including diffusion is equal to zero.

Comment: Those conditions can be set with the equations `det==0` and `der==0`. In this case, `jacobianmat - μ*diffmatrix` is the jacobian matrix of the system including diffusion. As you can see, the function `auxiliarfunction` takes into account everything I have said. It has the equilibrium point evaluated, and a solution to the equation `der==0`, that has to do with the derivative of the zero-eigenvalue. The problem is that that function is a mess and I haven't been able to get an implicit plot out of it. Instead, I am trying to parametrize the curve.

Comment: The functions `f1aux`, `f2aux`, `f3aux` and `f4aux` are used to take into account the equations for the equilibrium point, while `det` and `der` are the expressions used to find and continue the Turing bifurcation curve

Comment: Ok! It is nice approach (+1) in general case, but  not in this particular case. In what region  do you try to plot `auxiliarfunction==0`?

Comment: I actually don't know the bifurcation curve so I was considering `-0.0001<=ρh<=0.0001` and `0.03<=ν<=0.05` for no actual reason. That could change after I see the curve, of course

Comment: Please, see my answer.

Comment: The error message says basically that `Solve` failed to solve for the derivatives. If `NDSolve` cannot get the system into the explicit form $x’(t) = f(t, x(t))$, then it has to use an implicit integrator, and I think IDA is the only method available.  If you can solve for the derivatives and put the ODE in the form $x’(t)=f(t,x(t))$, then it should make non-IDA methods available.

Comment: I have tried giving the initial conditions for the derivatives but the warnings are still the same...

Comment: The error message is not talking about the initial conditions for the derivatives.  I wasn't either.  It's the ODE that has to be solved for the (highest order) derivatives in order to use a non-IDA method.

Comment: Oh you are right. My bad. The problem is that the first six equations of the system form a linear system or equations in the derivatives of the variables but the last equation is not so simple to solve for the free variable. In fact it will have two solutions related to the direction of the curve (forward or backward). I am not sure about the cost of that for Mathematica, but I will try.

Answer (score 2):

We don't need general expression of `auxiliarfunction`, but only some numerical to plot, therefore we can organize code as follows

```
Clear["Global`*"]

c = 0.002;
mu = 0.16;
ρa = 0.005;
c0 = 0.02;
γ = 0.02;
ϵ = 0.1;
d = 0.008;
e = 0.1;
f = 10.0;
D1 = 0.001;
D2 = 0.02;
D3 = 0.01;
D4 = 10^-7;

auxiliarfunction[x1_, x2_] := 
 Module[{ν = x1, ρh = x2, A, H, S, Y, f1, f2, f3, f4, μ, 
   jacobianmat, diffmatrix, det, der, ksquared}, 
  f1 = c*(S*A^2)/H - mu*A + ρa*Y;
  f2 = c*S*A^2 - ν*H + ρh*Y;
  f3 = c0 - γ*S - ϵ*Y*S;
  f4 = d*A - e*Y + Y^2/(1 + f*Y^2);
  jacobianmat = D[{f1, f2, f3, f4}, {{A, H, S, Y}}];
  diffmatrix = DiagonalMatrix[{D1, D2, D3, D4}];
  det = Det[jacobianmat - μ*diffmatrix] /. 
    NSolve[{f1 == 0, f2 == 0, f3 == 0, f4 == 0}, {A, H, S, Y}][[3]];
  der = Simplify[D[det, μ]];
  ksquared = NSolve[der == 0, μ][[1]]; det /. ksquared]
```

We can check how fast this function computed in one point

```
auxiliarfunction[.04, 1.0011 10^-5] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[]= {0.0240508, 4.45532*10^-8 + 1.35736*10^-6 I}
```

Ok, this function is complex and computation time is reasonable. Now we try to plot real part (it takes a time)

```
Plot3D[auxiliarfunction[x1, x2] // Re, {x1, 
  0.03, .05}, {x2, -.0001, .0001}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"ν", "ρh", ""}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 Mesh -> None]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: That seems nice but how can I get the level curve `auxiliarfunction[x1,x2]==0` from that plot?

Comment: It is not so simple since there is no curve, but probably some region.

Comment: Try to plot `Plot[auxiliarfunction[.04, x2] // Re, {x2, -.0001, .0001}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"\[Rho]h", ""}]` and also `Im`.

Comment: But in any case how could I extract the intersection of that plot with `z=0`?

Comment: Do you mean numerically evaluate some region around `z=0`? Let take some error, for instance, `eps=10^-6`, and `Plot3D` with option `PlotRange -> {-eps, eps}`.